# Using the same keystore with the same app but built from scratch again

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, release, google-play-console

I have trouble making a release in playstore now. It says when I upload an appbundle that it has a different sign key. Now to make the long story short, we redo the SAME app (the same app that was released a month ago in playstore) because it has a gazillion tons of bugs. I have used the same key store file that was used by the same app we released a month ago. The problem is playstore wouldnt accept the app bundle saying it was signed differently (mind you, we haven't sign the REDO/NEW version from scratch of the same app since we just plan to use the existing keystore to upload it immediately to playstore.

Can anyone shed me some light here on what to do? Thanks.

Its a flutter app btw

Comment: When you enrolled in Play Signing, didn't you have to create a second keystore for the upload key?

Comment: As far as I can remember, Im not the one who enrolled it but App Signing is enabled

Comment: If you go to the App Signing page of the Play Console, it will show you the upload certificate that it expects your App Bundle to be signed with. Compare this with the certificate of the keystore you're using (look at "keytool" commands).

Comment: Hi I got it working. Thanks! I forgot to put the signingConfig {} in the necessary file. Noob me lol. I think its just because I really dont want to make a release on fridays lmao

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio. Try following steps.

When you build Signed APK, In step 3rd or 4th, **CHECK BOTH** `V1 (Jar Signature) and V2 (Full APK Signature)`. See screenshot below.

[image: screenshot showing generate signed APK step choices]

Now upload that generated APK :)

Comment: Generate signed bundle or apk is missing in my android studio > build :( i cant seem to find a go around with it